# How can I compile this .c.txt file? - Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, compilation

I'm trying to compile one txt file using gcc in Ubuntu.

Procedure it like this.

1. I'm making test.c.txt file using `vi test.c.txt`
2. Using gcc -o, `gcc -o Q1.out test.c.txt`

Actually, when I practiced this code yesterday, I worked. but today, it doesn't work.
error message is like this.
`file not recognized: file format not recognized`

`collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

How can I compile this file?

Comment: Assuming the file contains C source code, renaming the file to `test.c` might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.txt` are text files, you have to tell gcc what file is that.

- If that file is in C programming language, you can tell gcc that with `-x` option like `gcc -xc -o Q1.out test.c.txt`.
- Or you can rename the file from `.txt` to `.c` and gcc will "guess" that the file is written in C language when the filename *ends* with `.c`.